# $\chi^2$ test failed

Tags: chi-squared-test, exponential-distribution, many-categories

I have data: http://pastebin.com/mcbbVQ0K 
[image]

As you can see it is typical Exp. But when I use chi-squared test it failed. What's wrong??
[image]

Details:[image]
[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Can you show the calculations you performed for each column?

Comment: i added prt screens witch calculations

Comment: These data clearly are *not* exponential.  If they were, there would be nearly a constant ratio of counts from one bin to the next.  You can scan down the column entitled "the real frequency" in the first image and watch the ratios get larger and larger: they start out at nearly 1:6 and quickly jump to 1:2 and larger.  There's no need to run a test at that point.  Why are you testing, anyway?  What do you accomplish by establishing that your data are not exponentially distributed?

Comment: @whuber look at last pic - i dont think that it is not exponential.

Comment: The graphics are not sufficiently quantitative to tell whether a curve is exponential.  *Lots* of rapidly decreasing curves *sort of look* exponential.  Trust the numbers, not your intuition.  But you're dodging the real issue here: what is the point of testing the distribution?

Comment: Data are differences between arrivals of customers - it is theoretically always Exponential

Comment: Maybe in theory it is but in practice it is not. The interesting question which so far none of us seems to have asked you is why you want to test this. With your sample size any reasonable test will reject almost any hypothesis.

Comment: @mdewey I have asked the "why" question twice now, with no constructive response.

Comment: @whuber so you have, not sure how I missed that in all the toing and froing.

Answer (score 1):

You have large numbers of very, very small expected frequencies. When the observed frequency is 1 this means that the value of

$$
\chi^2 = \frac{(O - E)^2}{E}
$$

becomes very, very large.

This is not going to work unless you group the frequencies.

Comment: I tried group frequencies but it doesnt work. Please can you tell me which frequencies should I group together?

Comment: You could argue grouping the entire tail where the expected proportion is smaller than 1 together.

Comment: OK. But look at row 3 chi-squared, there is number 436 - it is too much and gouping small frequencies together doesnt help mi change this value

Comment: I do not see a 436 there. It may well be that when you do group the values so that you get a more sensible value for chi-squared it still rejects the hypothesis that it is an exponential with the specified parameter.

Comment: The contribution to $\chi^2$ from the *most* frequent bin already is significant.  Therefore, although the small frequencies do contribute to the problem, eliminating them will not solve it.   The calculated fit is bad, period, and it's easy to detect that with so much data.

Comment: @whuber it means that it is not exponential distribution?

Answer (score 1):

As @mdewey pointed out you have too many categories and they have frequencies too low to be appropriate for the Chi squared test.

A rule for how high the expected count of the categories has to be is given in [this medicine journal article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3900058/#__sec2title)

> > The value of the cell expecteds should be 5 or more in at least 80% of the cells, and no cell should have an expected of less than one (3). This assumption is most likely to be met if the sample size equals at least the number of cells multiplied by 5. Essentially, this assumption specifies the number of cases (sample size) needed to use the χ2 for any number of cells in that χ2. This requirement will be fully explained in the example of the calculation of the statistic in the case study example.

The Chi-squared test is a non-parametric test but you have a geometric distributed variable. Why don't you use a test designed for a geometric variable to achieve a higher power?

Comment: 'The Chi-squared test is a non-parametric test but you have a geometric distributed variable.' But isn't the entire point of the test to see _if_ the data is geometrically distributed?

Comment: @Jarko I believe Hugh is suggesting there may be other tests, *specifically designed for the geometric distribution,* that could be more powerful than the chi-square.  That suggestion is puzzling mainly because the chi-square test (assuming it was correctly done) already establishes these data do not have a geometric distribution, so using a more powerful test would seem to be pointless.

Comment: @whuber Your point, in combination with the comment on the other answer should then be the final answer, not 'try another test'.